# SQL QUERY COMPLEX JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have several tables and I'd like to have an output of

*NAMA on MAHASISWA WHERE NIM on MAHASISWA = NIM_MHS on MHS_MAKUL Where (N_TUGAS = 'C' AND N_MID = 'B') AND ID_MHS_MAKUL ON NILAI_MAKUL = ID ON MHS_MAKUL*

Here the list of tables and columns

**MAHASISWA**

NIM | NAMA

**MHS_MAKUL**

ID | NIM_MHS

**NILAI_MAKUL**

N_TUGAS | N_MID | ID_MHS_MAKUL

I've tried to use this, but give me output "Table 'mahasiswa.nim' doesn't exist"

```
SELECT mahasiswa.NAMA, mahasiswa.NIM, mhs_makul.ID, nilai_makul.NIM_MHS,
       nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
FROM mahasiswa
INNER JOIN mahasiswa.NIM ON mhs_makul.NIM_MHS
INNER JOIN mhs_makul.ID ON nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
WHERE nilai_makul.N_TUGAS = 'C' AND nilai_makul.N_MID = 'B';
```

Comment: the argument of INNER JOIN is a table, but you are using a field

Comment: choose any one of mysql and sql-server, it refers different.

Comment: @YogeshSharma edited!

Answer (score 2):

Please learn the `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT mahasiswa.NAMA, mahasiswa.NIM, mhs_makul.ID, nilai_makul.NIM_MHS, nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
FROM mahasiswa
INNER JOIN mhs_makul ON mhs_makul.NIM_MHS = mahasiswa.NIM
INNER JOIN nilai_makul ON nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul = mhs_makul.ID
WHERE nilai_makul.N_TUGAS = 'C' AND nilai_makul.N_MID = 'B';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. The `join` clauses need to refer to a table, and then the `on` clauses have the condition this table is joined by:

```
SELECT     mahasiswa.NAMA,
           mahasiswa.NIM,
           mhs_makul.ID,
           nilai_makul.NIM_MHS,
           nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
FROM       mahasiswa
INNER JOIN mhs_makul ON mahasiswa.NIM = mhs_makul.NIM_MHS
INNER JOIN nilai_makul ON mhs_makul.ID = nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
WHERE      nilai_makul.N_TUGAS = 'C' AND
           nilai_makul.N_MID = 'B';
```

Answer (score 1):

the join condition is not written right , try this

```
SELECT mahasiswa.NAMA, mahasiswa.NIM, mhs_makul.ID, nilai_makul.NIM_MHS, nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul  
FROM mahasiswa  
INNER JOIN mhs_makul  
ON mhs_makul.NIM_MHS = mahasiswa.NIM   
INNER JOIN nilai_makul  
ON nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul = mhs_makul.ID   
WHERE nilai_makul.N_TUGAS = 'C'   
AND nilai_makul.N_MID = 'B';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT mahasiswa.NAMA, mahasiswa.NIM, mhs_makul.ID, nilai_makul.NIM_MHS,
       nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
FROM mahasiswa
INNER JOIN mhs_makul ON mahasiswa.NIM = mhs_makul.NIM_MHS
INNER JOIN nilai_makul ON mhs_makul.ID = nilai_makul.ID_mhs_makul
WHERE nilai_makul.N_TUGAS = 'C' AND nilai_makul.N_MID = 'B';
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) the documentation for `JOIN`, this is how it's defined:

```
table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
```

So, you need to specify table names in `JOIN` and column names in `ON` clause